# Center a table horizontally in a div

Tags: css

I am trying to center a table within a div but the table can be of varying length. The code looks something like this:

```
<div>
     <table>
     <tr> .... </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

The `div` element is of course `display:block` and of course takes up the entire horizontal space on the page but I cannot figure out how to set the padding to auto and just center the table in the `div`

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are block level elements. You can set the `width` of the table and set `margin: auto`

If the `width` varies you may be able to use a percentage or a combination of `width` and `min/max-width`.

Comment: Thanks! I realized the flex example below was useful, but the main thing that I was being oblivious of was that tables are block-level elements! Duh... Thanks - my problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If the `table` has an explicit width, you could just use `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

```
table { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Alternatively, if you want to use flexboxes, set the `display` of the parent element to `flex`, and use `justify-content: center` for horizontal centering.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfect. Now, the only problem is that the "max-width:600px; style attribute that I put on the div element gets overidden and it gets expanded to the entire page. Any way to solve this?

Comment: @WalkerFarrow I'd suggest reading up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). If you make an [example](http://jsfiddle.net), I can look at it.